# Routing table information

Tags: ip, routing

I want to find all the possible ip addresses my router can send packet to.
I know there is a command route print that give let me see the default gateway,
but I want to get all the possible ip address the default gateway can send packets to.
A reference to C++ API or command in the cmd will be great.

Comment: `all the possible ip addresses`??? Your router can send to any IP address. The question is - will the package reach it's destination.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default gateway (0.0.0.0/0), then you can send to all of them.  Or at least all of them that are valid.  Some networks are reserved for [private usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) or other purposes by various standards.